# Trying to update a field in Oracle based on a select statement - getting subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update a field on a table the query needs to get the value from a 2nd table and use that to get the data from a 3rd table. I keep getting the "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" Any help is appreciated.

update ord_detail set cuser1 = (select c.email from contact c,ord_detail m join orders o on o.ID = m.orders_ID where c.email is not null)
where EXISTS (select email from contact,orders where orders.contact_id2 = contact.id)

Comment: Without data model, it is difficult to guess what represents what and how are those tables related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide further information like the results of your sub selects, it's not 100% clear what exactly is your problem. You should check those results and if this does not answer your question, please provide the details.
My guess is that this sub query will give multiple rows because you are missing a join from the table "contact" to one of the other tables:

```
select c.email from contact c,ord_detail m 
join orders o on o.ID = m.orders_ID where c.email is not null
```

Therefore, this sub query will always lead to many rows as result unless the table "contact" contains one row only whose column email is not null.